# CSS table design not working

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have this table:

```
<table style="width: 512px; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background: #00f; height: 9px; width: 9px;"></td>
<td style="background: #0f0; height: 9px;"></td>
<td style="background: #f00; height: 9px; width: 9px;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please no "do not use tables" kind of messages. I am using tables here for clarity, trying to solve my issue.

The problem is that I see the result as http://ioj.com/v/if64c

Where is the green line? It should be 496x9!

Comment: Try adding a `&nbsp;` inside the cells. Sometimes browsers get a bit funky if it sees empty cells.

Comment: I tried it on FF 3.6.6, and it looked fine. Which browser is causing the issue?

Comment: Yeah I find it works on FF 3.6.6 but not Chrome 6.0.453.1 dev (both Linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

to your table's css, it works.

(ref [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_table-layout.asp))

This is because tables will auto-calculate column width based on cell contents by default.

Comment: Yep, use `table-layout: fixed` wherever possible. It is faster to render and much more predictable cross-browser than the default ‘auto’ table layout algorithm.

Comment: I did not know about this, this is also solves another issues I have had with tables earlier! Thanks so much for this wonderful answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width: 512px; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background: #00f; height: 9px; width: 9px;"></td>
<td style="background: #0f0; height: 9px; width: 9px;"></td><!-- use specific width -->
<td style="background: #f00; height: 9px; width: 9px;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```